# Yahoo recently pulled the plug on their stocks API. What are "Yahoo-finance" related posts and its tag's fates?

Tags: discussion, tags, dead-tags

Just as the beginning of the title states; Yahoo pulled a fast one without even breathing a word.

Since this (in some ways) relates to coders who have coded for the use of Yahoo Finance (I used a PHP method), there have been a few posts show up these past few days in regards to it.

I (also) have used it for a long time and it suddenly stopped working recently and threw me a whole bunch of errors.

Of course, the first thing I did was Google that (blunt error) message of theirs.

I knew what to look for (on the site) and rectified the problem quickly by not calling that script, and the questions arise.

Many coders will also have to take matters in hand as I did.

Here is one post that I found here on Stack Overflow:

[Has Yahoo suddenly today terminated its finance download API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47064776/1415724)

I have to say that my first finding was https://www.stockmarketeye.com/blog/quote-issues-due-to-changes-at-yahoo-finance/ because I was hoping to find the "real" reason for Yahoo suddenly "pulling the plug".

I executed the file that accessed the stocks data directly, where I was presented with this (rather blunt error) message when a script was trying to access the stocks data (I'm sure many others have seen that same message, and some may not already know of its existence):

> It has come to our attention that this service is being used in violation of the Yahoo Terms of Service. As such, the service is being discontinued. For all future markets and equities data research, please refer to finance.yahoo.com.

What I would like to know is:

- How will this affect [yahoo-finance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yahoo-finance) (already existing) posts and (possible) future posts, should they want to add that tag?
- Since Yahoo doesn't let stock data be made available, will the tag get burninated?
- Will that tag still be made available to be used for new questions, even though it's no longer supported by Yahoo?

I have to say that there may be some who may not know what to do about it and stand to ask a question in regards to this.

The Q&A I posted above, could probably be served as a canonical/community wiki; I'm thinking out loud here.

Comment: I've created a new tag for discussing tags like this.

Comment: @StephenLeppik that is clearly an Halloween inspired tag name ...

Comment: @rene Nah, it's just the first thing I thought of for the tag. It wasn't meant to be Halloween-related.

Comment: I'm curious to know why the question I posted suddently received 2 minus votes. Can those persons enlighten me please? I'm not ticked off here *lol!* I just want to know why. The fact that Yahoo did that, is of very serious nature.

Comment: Maybe because of excessive use of slang? I can infer the meaning of "pull the plug" and "pulled a fast one without even breathing a word" from the context, but maybe people didn't like it.

Comment: @anatolyg If people downvoted the post for what you say is slang, then that's just a cheap shot. Btw, "cheap shot" is an expression just like what people and/or you think are "slang". Those are two different animals entirely.

Comment: @StephenLeppik Seems somebody didn't like the edit https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/358883/6 you made *lol!* as it received a downvotes since. I didn't think there was anything with my original title.

Comment: I thought it was too long.

Comment: @StephenLeppik That shouldn't matter. I don't think people have *that* a short attention/reading span.

Answer (score 52):

Remember to edit the tag wikis to note that Yahoo has pulled the plug.

Burnination is **not** a good idea here, as the tag still doesn't meet any of the criteria for that fate. There could still be interesting questions on the subject, such as converting old code to use a new API.

Let's create a CCWQ&A (**C**anonical **C**ommunity **W**iki **Q**uestion & **A**nswer) explaining that the service was dropped, and monitor the tag feeds with dupehammer poised and ready, possibly with the help of SOCVR.

…this is why most APIs have a sunset period, rather than just being dropped with no warning at all.

Update: use [Has Yahoo suddenly today terminated its finance download API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47064776/6388243) as the canonical for this.

Comment: YACAFSOCCA! (**Y**et **A**nother **C**onfusing **A**bbreviation **F**or the **S**ake **O**f **C**reating **C**onfusing **A**bbreviations.)

Comment: Isn't there a way to prevent a tag from being added to new questions?

Comment: *"just downvote new questions"* - I'm not familiar with the API, but it seems to me that there could conceivably be interesting new questions relevant to the tag that are useful _precisely_ because of the fact that it's been pulled. Someone trying to port old code that used the API to instead use a different provider will have to figure out what the API's behaviour was without the benefit of actually being able to test it; asking about details of the now-dead API's behaviour and hoping that somebody on Stack Overflow remembers, while an unusual question type, seems perfectly legitimate to me.

Comment: @MarkAmery that's… a very good point. Will change.

Comment: TANSTAAGA .... :-)

Comment: @StephenC There ain't no such thing as a good abbreviation?

Comment: Acronym .... but you got it :-)

Answer (score 41):

One day, the last computer in the world that understands COBOL will be permanently shut down leaving the fate of the language itself in a state of flux. Well, that's assuming that COBOL lets that happen.

That it's no longer used doesn't make something off-topic for the site, we'll continue to accrue relics each year that we exist. I can't even hazard a guess on how many existentially-challenged payment processing systems we continue to document :) They're a piece of history, and something someone had to get done, probably pretty urgently, one day however long ago.

So with that said, just *curate* the tag like you would any other museum exhibit. Be judicious with duplicate finding and merging, edit the tag wiki  to point to any external resources (e.g. replacements) and just let it be something that once existed that folks used.

Comment: Yeah, I honestly don't see why these tags would be such a problem, other than the occasional question from someone who hasn't yet got the memo that the API is no longer in service (something burninating a tag isn't going to prevent anyway).

Comment: @BoltClock and/or Tim. Seeing the questions thread on the [yahoo-finance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yahoo-finance) tag. Would it be too bold to ask if the new posts were automatically closed as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47064776/has-yahoo-suddenly-today-terminated-its-finance-download-api or another similar question that shows reasons/altenate options? I've place a vote to close as a duplicate under a few new questions, so is that the only course of action to take? Or have a warning pop up for the use of the tag.

Comment: Yes, we never know when [that last line of code is coming](http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2015/11/13/the-last-ever-line-of-code/)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'd oppose the automated duplicate vote since [there could still be good non-duplicate questions with this tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358883/yahoo-recently-pulled-the-plug-on-their-stocks-api-what-are-yahoo-finance-rel?cb=1#comment529300_358884). An automated warning would be *great* (as it would be with many, many other tags, for many diverse reasons), but Stack Overflow doesn't support such a thing and a few-hundred-question tag ain't realistically gonna get the devs to implement it. I fear the best solution is for you to keep doing what you're doing.

Comment: @MarkAmery Fair enough and a good point taken. Maybe have some type of warning pop up when that tag is used, to let people know about it. I don't know how they're going to handle those, since there could be too many ways to go about it, or just not do anything about the tag and leaving well enough alone.

Comment: that won't happen fast. the dutch irs is still actively hiring cobol programmers :-P

Comment: _"One day, the last computer in the world that understands COBOL will be permanently shut down leaving the fate of the language itself in a state of flux."_ - not according to what I have seen in the 6 years working in banking. COBOL is freaking EVERYWHERE. Clue - if any API or spec requires "no more than 80 characters" I bet you all the pie you can eat it is running COBOL.

Comment: It would be nice if somebody could write a canonical Q&A on the main site talking about the closure - I see a lot of questions (particularly in the pandas tag) from "people who didn't get the memo".

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ *"It would be nice if somebody could write a canonical Q&A"* -  Wouldn't this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/47064776/1415724 that I included in my post qualify as one, in your opinion? Did you also notice the warning they added for the tag? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yahoo-finance - Being: "PLEASE NOTE : THIS API HAS BEEN DISCONTINUED BY YAHOO.". Maybe they should have put that in bold.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Apologies, I did not see that in your question. But I did discover that link eventually and have been using it as a target since.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ ah, no worries. Oh, I edited my comment also; you may want to reload it. Seems like something's been done, but as you said; some just may not be getting the memo *lol!* Edit: Oh cool :)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yup, saw it. Unfortunately, markup does not apply to tag excerpts :D

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ ah... that's a shame. I didn't know that also. Maybe.... a feature request? *haha!* - Tim: hint hint, nudge nudge.