# It's time to bury [digg]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, dead-tags

[The original [image] was a social tech news/link aggregator](http://web.archive.org/web/20100315064339/http://digg.com//) that operated from 2004 to 2012. It was described as [one of the influences in the creation of Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/09/11/help-us-beta-test/). Digg [provided an API](http://web.archive.org/web/20110428072907/http://developers.digg.com/) and about 60 questions were asked about it under the [digg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/digg) tag, which was appropriate at the time. However, that Digg and its APIs have now been gone for seven years.

The very different site that is [now operating under the Digg brand](https://techcrunch.com/2012/07/31/the-new-digg-arrives-ahead-of-schedule/) briefly operated a Digg Reader API. Only a few questions were ever asked about it, and [that service has also shut down](https://techcrunch.com/2018/03/14/alas-digg-reader-is-shutting-down-at-the-end-of-march/). The remaining site has no API. Digg is no longer a relevant topic for Stack Overflow.

**I propose that the [digg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/digg) tag (68 questions) be removed, and questions asking only about the obsolete Digg APIs should be closed or deleted.** Questions that used the Digg APIs or websites as examples or context, but still have other useful content, might just need to be edited or retagged.

[image]

Comment: Normally, I'd say that obsolescence of a technology is not grounds for closure, much less deletion. However, I guess web APIs may be an exception. When they're no longer supported, they become completely unusable and worthless.

Comment: I am also usually for preserving content, but this seemed like a particularly pointless case. There is some historical curiosity, but I'm not sure that's enough.

Comment: This has [happened to a tag before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358883/6083675) and the decision was to edit the tag wiki but not take any moderation action on the questions with the tag. Is there a problem other than the service being obsolete that makes this something that needs action? Why should we expend our finite resources (votes, time) on this?

Comment: @Laurel I would make that an answer so it can be voted on

Comment: @Laurel Good cross-ref, thanks. Generally, Stack Overflow wants to have content that makes the internet better. This is a small but relatively clear case of useless content that nobody wants to land on from Google. COBOL (an example used in the other question) was an extremely widely-used language and answers about it could be relevant historically and in understanding old site. The yahoo-finance tags had hundreds of questions and would have taken a lot more work to clean up, and the API was used for enough serious purposes that the questions are more likely to still have useful information.

Comment: For *historical curiosity* we have [retrocomputing.se](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/) ...

Comment: Somewhat relevant is the demise of parse.com and the fate of the corresponding tag on Stack Overflow proper since then. If any question is specific to the API and isn't generally applicable otherwise, it can be closed as not reproducible because the problems described can literally never be reproduced again unless the service were somehow restored.

Comment: It's interesting that the [tag:yahoo-finance] tag is still being actively used.  There are 750+ questions with the tag, and quite a number asked this year (15 by my count).  Sometimes they have other tags — people aren't good at reading tag summaries, or ignore them even if they do read them.  Or it has somehow morphed into a tag for the generic https://finance.yahoo.com/ site rather than the https://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes/… service that used to exist but reputedly doesn't any more (`curl` indicates a redirect — but the redirect to `http://download.finance.yahoo.com/` doesn't resolve.

Comment: whenever tags get active again, do burninated questions relating to it get restored? I know closed questions can be reopened but not sure on deleted ones

Comment: @Malky.Kid Deleted questions *can* be restored, but I don't think there's any precedent for mass-undeletion like that. We wouldn't generally delete on-topic well-asked questions that might be useful to future visitors, so it doesn't come up. I suggest that this is a rare case where we can be confident that nobody will need this information in the future.

Comment: @rene Thanks for the publicity, but I have no idea whether that would be on-topic!

Comment: @wizzwizz4 let's hope it is not ...

Comment: @rene For the record, [I asked on Retrocomputing meta](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/703/278); if the answer is no then DON'T post [tag:digg] questions on Retrocomputing!

Comment: How did this even come up? (Serious question) I feel like for an obsolete API like this, it would never be bumped, or show up in search results, or even get clicks from Google. The questions and answers will be ignored and will "go away" by themselves. So like @Laurel says why expend effort on them?

Comment: @andrewtweber Stack Overflow is supposed to be curated and maintained. I was going through and editing a bunch of old questions and ran into these.  I figured it made more sense to get rid of them than try to improve them. But if we do keep them, we need to maintain them, or else we're polluting the internet instead of making it a better place.